# Android app making SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I am making a game and I need 2 different views. The Main Menu and the actual game view. Should I have a separate surfaceview for the main menu and the game view and just switch the views with the setContentView() function in the main activity? Or is there  better way of doing it?

Comment: Why don't you use two separate activities?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with app making quite yet. I only just started making apps a few weeks ago. Could you briefly explain how I would create and change between new activities please.

Comment: Take a look at Android Breakout (https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/).  It uses Android views for the main menu and GLSurfaceView for the game; these are hosted in separate activities.  I can't tell from your question if you're doing the same sort of thing, but you can at least see how the activities interact.